# How to override a default value, via lenses, only if incoming value is not Nothing

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm basically trying to override a bunch of default values in a record only if the user-specific values are NOT `Nothing`. Is it possible to do it via lenses?

```
import qualified Data.Default as DD

instance DD.Def Nouns where
  def  = Nouns
    {
      -- default values for each field come here
    }

lookupHStore :: HStoreList -> Text -> Maybe Text

mkNounsFromHStoreList :: HStoreList -> Nouns
mkNounsFromHStoreList h = (DD.def Nouns)
  & depSingular .~ (lookupHStore h "dep_label_singular")
  -- ERROR: Won't compile because Text and (Maybe Text) don't match
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do. Please include the definition of `Nouns` and `HStoreList`, expected input/output, and any error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your own combinator:

```
(~?) :: ASetter' s a -> Maybe a -> s -> s
s ~? Just a  = s .~ a
s ~? Nothing = id
```

Which you can use just like `.~`:

```
mkNounsFromHStoreList :: HStoreList -> Nouns
mkNounsFromHStoreList h =
  DD.def
    & myNoun1 ~? lookupHStore h "potato"
    & myNoun2 ~? lookupHStore h "cheese"
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed. And probably should be contributed upstream.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a job for [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative). [`Maybe`'s `Alternative` instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-707) implements *left-biased choice* - its `<|>` chooses the first non-`Nothing` value.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Semigroup

data Foo = Foo {
    bar :: Maybe Int,
    baz :: Maybe String
}
```

I'm going to implement a [`Semigroup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Semigroup) instance for `Foo` which lifts `<|>` point-wise over the record fields. So the operation `x <> y` overrides the fields of `y` with the matching non-`Nothing` fields of `x`. (You can also use [the `First` monoid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First), it does the same thing.)

```
instance Semigroup Foo where
    f1 <> f2 = Foo {
        bar = bar f1 <|> bar f2,
        baz = baz f1 <|> baz f2
    }

ghci> let defaultFoo = Foo { bar = Just 2, baz = Just "default" }
ghci> let overrides = Foo { bar = Just 8, baz = Nothing }
ghci> overrides <> defaultFoo
Foo {bar = Just 8, baz = Just "default"}
```

Note that you don't need lenses for this, although they might be able to help you make the implementation of `(<>)` a little terser.

When the user gives you a partially-filled-in `Foo`, you can fill in the rest of the fields by appending your default `Foo`.

```
fillInDefaults :: Foo -> Foo
fillInDefaults = (<> defaultFoo)
```

---

One fun thing you can do with this is factor the `Maybe` out of `Foo`'s definition.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Semigroup
import Data.Functor.Identity

data Foo f = Foo {
    bar :: f Int,
    baz :: f String
}
```

The `Foo` I originally wrote above is now equivalent to `Foo Maybe`. But now you can express invariants like "this `Foo` has all of its fields filled in" without duplicating `Foo` itself.

```
type PartialFoo = Foo Maybe  -- the old Foo
type TotalFoo = Foo Identity  -- a Foo with no missing values
```

The `Semigroup` instance, which only relied on `Maybe`'s instance of `Alternative`, remains unchanged,

```
instance Alternative f => Semigroup (Foo f) where
    f1 <> f2 = Foo {
        bar = bar f1 <|> bar f2,
        baz = baz f1 <|> baz f2
    }
```

but you can now generalise `defaultFoo` to an arbitrary `Applicative`.

```
defaultFoo :: Applicative f => Foo f
defaultFoo = Foo { bar = pure 2, baz = pure "default" }
```

Now, with a little bit of `Traversable`-inspired categorical nonsense,

```
-- "higher order functors": functors from the category of endofunctors to the category of types
class HFunctor t where
    hmap :: (forall x. f x -> g x) -> t f -> t g

-- "higher order traversables",
-- about which I have written a follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44187945/7951906
class HFunctor t => HTraversable t where
    htraverse :: Applicative g => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> t f -> g (t Identity)
    htraverse eta = hsequence . hmap eta
    hsequence :: Applicative f => t f -> f (t Identity)
    hsequence = htraverse id

instance HFunctor Foo where
    hmap eta (Foo bar baz) = Foo (eta bar) (eta baz)
instance HTraversable Foo where
    htraverse eta (Foo bar baz) = liftA2 Foo (Identity <$> eta bar) (Identity <$> eta baz)
```

`fillInDefaults` can be adjusted to express the invariant that the resulting `Foo` is not missing any values.

```
fillInDefaults :: Alternative f => Foo f -> f TotalFoo
fillInDefaults = hsequence . (<> defaultFoo)

-- fromJust (unsafely) asserts that there aren't
-- any `Nothing`s in the output of `fillInDefaults`
fillInDefaults' :: PartialFoo -> TotalFoo
fillInDefaults' = fromJust . fillInDefaults
```

Probably overkill for what you need, but it's still pretty neat.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a possible solution, but I'm still looking for a better one!

```
mkNounsFromHStoreList :: HStoreList -> Nouns
mkNounsFromHStoreList h = (DD.def Nouns)
  & depSingular %~ (overrideIfJust (lookupHStore h "dep_label_singular"))
  -- and more fields come here...
  where
    overrideIfJust val x = maybe x id val
```

Comment: You do realise `overrideIfJust == flip fromMaybe`?

Answer (score 0):

How about just using [`fromMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) instead of creating an instance of `Default`?

**EDIT**: Since you seem to want to use the `Default` for other purposes as well:

```
λ > import Data.Default
λ > import Data.Maybe
λ > :t fromMaybe def
fromMaybe def :: Default a => Maybe a -> a
```

This seems to be what you are after.

Comment: Need the default instance for other things, eg. displaying the default values to the user in the UI.

Comment: Right, you can still use the `Default` instance if you need it. I think the function you are after in order to use the default value is simply `fromMaybe`: `fromMaybe def` should have type `Maybe Nouns -> Nouns` in this context. :-)