# What should a "higher order Traversable" class look like?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, category-theory, traversable

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44186072/7951906) I made up on the spot something which looks a bit like a "higher order `Traversable`": like `Traversable` but for functors from the category of endofunctors on Hask to Hask.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Data.Functor.Compose
import Data.Functor.Identity

class HFunctor t where
    hmap :: (forall x. f x -> g x) -> t f -> t g

class HFunctor t => HTraversable t where
    htraverse :: Applicative g => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> t f -> g (t Identity)
    htraverse eta = hsequence . hmap eta
    hsequence :: Applicative f => t f -> f (t Identity)
    hsequence = htraverse id
```

I made `HFunctor` a superclass of `HTraversable` because it seemed right, but when I sat down to write `hmapDefault` I got stuck.

```
hmapDefault :: HTraversable t => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> t f -> t g
hmapDefault eta = runIdentity . htraverse (Identity . eta)

-- • Couldn't match type ‘x’ with ‘g x’
--   Expected type: f x -> Identity x
--     Actual type: f x -> Identity (g x)
```

`Identity . eta` has a type `forall y. f y -> Identity (g y)`, so when I pass it into `htraverse` `g` unifies with `Identity` and `x` has to unify with both `y` and `g y`, so it fails because the traversal function is not a natural transformation.

I attempted to patch it up using `Compose`:

```
hmapDefault :: HTraversable t => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> t f -> t g
hmapDefault eta = runIdentity . getCompose . htraverse (Compose . Identity . eta)
```

Now `Compose . Identity . eta` is a natural transformation, but you can't `htraverse` with it because you don't know `Applicative g`. And even if you could do that, the `runIdentity` call returns `g (t Identity)` and you're left with no way to put the `g` back inside the `t`.

---

I then realised that my `htraverse` isn't really analogous to plain old `traverse`. The traversal function of `traverse` puts the new value *inside* an `Applicative` effect, making the type expression bigger. So `htraverse` should probably look like this:

```
class HFunctor t => HTraversable t where
    htraverse :: Applicative a => (forall x. f x -> a (g x)) -> t f -> a (t g)
```

It's promising that this definition looks more like `Traversable`, and `hmapDefault` goes off without a hitch,

```
hmapDefault :: HTraversable t => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> t f -> t g
hmapDefault eta = runIdentity . htraverse (Identity . eta)
```

but I'm struggling to come up with a good analogue for `sequenceA`. I tried

```
hsequence :: (HTraversable t, Applicative f) => t f -> f (t Identity)
hsequence = htraverse (fmap Identity)
```

but I can't come up with a way of implementing `htraverse` in terms of `hsequence`. As before, `f` is not a natural transformation.

```
htraverse f = hsequence . hmap f

-- • Couldn't match type ‘x’ with ‘g x’
--   Expected type: f x -> a x
--     Actual type: f x -> a (g x)
```

I suspect I have my `hsequence` type signature wrong. Is `Applicative` the problem - do I need to go all the way up to [indexed monads](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/Kleisli.pdf)? What should a class for "traversable functors from the `Functor` category to Hask" look like? Does such a thing even exist?

Comment: If `~>` is the natural transformation arrow, then `sequenceA :: (Applicative f) => t . f ~> f . t`, which can be reinterpreted in a higher context, so that's what I'd focus on.  But yeah looks like you need higher applicatives for that.

Comment: @luqui I was under the impression that higher applicatives don't actually exist, it's indexed monads or bust. ["In general, demonic activity makes this structure hard to attain. Applicative functors sequence computations with no value dependency: in `(<*>) :: Applicative a => a (s -> t) -> a s -> a t` there is no way for the value of the function computation to influence our choice of
argument computation, only the way in which its value is used in turn."](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/Kleisli.pdf)

Comment: Interesting!  My normal approach is useless here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In first order, we have `sequence = traverse id`.

Here the first argument of `htraverse` has type `forall x. f x -> a (g x)`, we can't have `id`, but we can try with an isomorphism instead. For `f x` to be isomorphic to `a (g x)`, we can pick `f ~ Compose a g`.

```
htraverse = hsequence . hmap (Compose . eta)

hsequence :: Applicative a => t (Compose a g) -> a (t g)
hsequence = htraverse getCompose
```

Comment: I take it you meant `htraverse eta = hsequence . hmap (Compose . eta)` and `hsequence :: Applicative a => t (Compose a g) -> a (t g)`? This appears to work! Thanks!

Comment: Oops, that's what I meant indeed.

Comment: In that case I think the most elegant version of these types is `htraverse :: Applicative a => (f ~> Compose a g) -> t f -> a (t g)`, `hsequence :: Applicative a => t (Compose a g) -> a (t g)`. Then the code of `htraverse` and `hsequence` is exactly the same as for regular `Traversable`

Comment: Nowadays we have: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rank2classes/docs/Rank2.html#t:Traversable